# Manipulate runs fine normally, but gives errors as a CDF

Tags: manipulate, export, cdf-format, deployment

I've simplified my code to what can reproduce my error. Basically, I have two lines:

```
 spherePoint[x_] := Graphics3D[Sphere[{x, 0, 0}, 1]]; 

 Manipulate[Show[spherePoint[m]], {{m, 1}, -Pi/2, Pi/2}]
```

This runs perfectly fine when I evaluate it in *Mathematica* notebook, but when I do a CDF preview (or export), it gives me the error

> ```
> Show::gtype: spherePoint is not a type of graphics. >>
> ```

What gives?! Show should accept a `Graphics3D`, and `spherePoint` is a graphics 3D object! (I'm not sure about the last part of that sentence, because it's a function that gives a graphics 3d object, but I don't know what that implies for the program)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add the option `SaveDefinitions -> True` to your `Manipulate` command.

Comment: Of course you want to include an option such as `PlotRange->3` in the `Show` expression; otherwise, the sphere doesn't appear to move as you change the slider.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem is that exporting `Manipulate/Animate/DynamicModule` only saves definitions of scoped symbols (green).  Specifically, it doesn't know your definition of `spherePoint` and, in CDF Player, you don't have the option to execute that command.

You can get around this using the `SaveDefinitions -> True` or by putting those "external" definitions in the `Initialization` option.

My experience is that `Initialization` is usually a bit more cross-platform independent.  Here's how to use it:

```
spherePoint[x_] := Graphics3D[Sphere[{x, 0, 0}, 1]];

Manipulate[
 Show[spherePoint[m]], {{m, 1}, -Pi/2, Pi/2},
 Initialization :> (
    spherePoint[x_] := Graphics3D[Sphere[{x, 0, 0}, 1]]
 )
]
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I go about intializing multiple function definitions? What comes after the :> isn't a list, and in my program I have three functions to define. It works perfectly using SaveDefinitions though.

Comment: @NeuroFuzzy Note how the value of the `Initialization` is wrapped in parentheses. You can wrap an arbitrary block of code in those parentheses - i.e. (`f1[x_] := def1; f2[x_] := def2`)

Comment: @Kuba I have no problem with edits and I think you've made a net improvement - thanks! One thing: The original question concerned CDF Player. When I originally answered the question, that seemed important to me. In particular, when you open the document in CDF Player, you don't even have the option to execute that line where `spherePoint` is defined. I'll add that part back in.

Comment: @MarkMcClure Ah, now I get that. Sure.